# How to fix incorrectly sorted albums whose titles contain numbers

Tags: ipod, music, album

I have an iPod Classic 160gb 6g. In Cover Flow it appears that some of the albums containing numbers in the title will end up at the end of the alphabet. For example, this is the end of the Cover Flow:

- Under A Blood Red Sky - U2
- Who's Gonna Ride Your Wild Horses - U2
- Bringing Down The Horse - The Wallflowers
- xx - The xx
- Young The Giant - Young The Giant
- Eagles Greatest Hits Volume 2 - The Eagles
- Erasure: Pop! 20 Hits - Erasure
- 99.5 The Mountain Homegrown Vol. 6 - Live at The Soiled Dove Underground - Various Artists

However, there are some albums, such as these, which are alphabetized correctly:

- Greatest Hits, Vol. 1: The Singles - Goo Goo Dolls
- The 2nd Law - Muse
- TKOL RMX 1234567 [Disc 1] - Radiohead

Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Verify that the "Sort Album" is set correctly in iTunes. It may be set to have the numbers at the beginning of the title for some reason, and iTunes sorts album names that start with numbers after "z".

[image: iTunes info window, sorting tab]

Answer (score 0):

Make Album = Album Artist = Artist.
Those three attributes should be same.
Backup your data before doing this.
This is the only method worked for me.
I moved artist tag to comment tag for future.